# find GCD in a one line code using function

Tags: c, algorithm

the question is you have write a program that find the GCD of two number and you should define a function to do that but the challenge is that the body of function shouldn't be more than 1 line and you can use only one semicolon! I tried so far and wrote this. do you have any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bmm(int m, int n) {
    while(m!=n) int a = m > n ? m -= n : n -= m;
    return m;
}

int main() {
    int m, n;
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    if (m < 0)m = -m;
    if (n < 0)n = -n;
    printf("%d", bmm(m,n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They probably wanted it to be recursive. Also you can read about the Euclid's GCD algorithm. It is similar to yours but  more efficient (less steps).

Comment: Arguably `while(m!=n) int a = m > n ? m -= n : n -= m;` is two lines. You can pile as much code on one line as you like (subject to compiler limits).

Comment: int gcd_euclid(int a, int b) { return a % b == 0 ? b : gcd(b, a % b); }

Comment: Or `int bmm(int m, int n) { return n ? bmm(n, m % n) : m; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it in one line in a recurive way:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    return (b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if...else statement like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bmm(int m, int n)
{
   while(m!=0&&n!=0)
   {
      if(m>n)m-=n;
      else n-=m;
   }
   return m;
}

int main() 
{
   int m, n;
   scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
   if (m < 0)m =- m;
   if (n < 0)n =- n;
   printf("\n GCD = %d", bmm(m,n));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly conform to the requirements mentioned in the original post

Comment: This is just restating OP's `?:` as an `if/else`. This is [arguably] _more_ lines. And, technically, OP's solution was more than a single line [because of the `while`].

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes I know but also there is a problem here :                                        int a = m > n ? m -= n : n -= m;